# SlickGrid in Vuejs and overflow:scroll

Tags: vue.js, slickgrid

So I have a problem with width of columns. I need to use `overflow-y: scroll;` in my grid. When the count of rows is large and grid overflowing it's OK. But when the count of rows is a few and grid don't overflowing, the space for scroll is right where it should be, but the right column doesn't see this space for scrollbar and collide with it. It looks like the content in right column is hiding under space for scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found how to fix a problem. The problem is based in this stuff - SlickGrid can't calculate width of column if you set in css style `overflow-y: scroll;`. You need to use in creating grid `grid.options.alwaysShowVerticalScroll = true;`. This stuff is working alright.